# bash seeing parameter as function

Tags: git, bash

I have this function to make make it simpeler for me to push to git. It works fine with pushing without arguments, however when I pass a parameter to the function I get `-bash: parameter: command not found`. For as far as I know, I am calling the function correctly.

```
function gitPush {
  if ($1)
    then
    if ($2)
     then
     git push $2 $1
    else
     git push origin $1
    fi
  else
    git push origin master
  fi
}
```

When I call it using `gitPush` it works fine, however `gitPush branch` does not work.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

I don't know if it affects the execution of the function (expect not), but I am using Putty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`($1)` isn't doing what you think it does - it is attempting to execute the command stored in the first argument, in a subshell.

To test for the existence of an argument, you can use the following:

```
if [[ -n $1 ]]
```

Or to simply count the arguments, you can use the following:

```
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you might do this quite a lot shorter with:

```
function gitPush {
    local remote=${2:-origin}
    local branch=${1:-master}
    git push "${remote}" "${branch}"
}
```

But all-in-all this is probably not something you would want to use anyway.

in your `.gitconfig` you could add:

```
[push]
default = tracking
```

That way wou will always push to the tracked remote of the current branch if you do not supply arguments.

Comment: Thank you for showing me the shorter way of writing my function. Though it is not the answer to the question what I was doing wrong I think I will use this option to rewrite the function I have. I'll also take a look into my `.gitconfig` file

Comment: @Jelmergu: well, you should not have tagged this "git" in the first place as it is a basic shell scripting error; git had nothing to do with that. ;-) But since you did, I thought I'd answer anyway .;-)

Comment: aha, I thought that since I was using a function of git it should have been tagged anyway. Either way I am happy that I did tag it with git. I now have my answer and a better way to do what I wanted.